# Solving $ydx + (\frac{e^x}{y}-1)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the equation:

$$
y\,dx + (\frac{e^x}{y}-1)\,dy = 0
$$

My question is why cant i just integrate like this:

$$
\int y \, dx + \int (\frac{e^x}{y}-1) \, dy = C
$$

Getting:

$$
yx + e^x\ln|y| - y = C
$$

Namely:

$$
e^x\ln|y| + y(x-1) = C \Rightarrow \ln|y| +y(x-1)e^{-x} = C
$$

There is no such option in the answers so i conclude that I’m wrong somehow, but why?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a better answer I can give you other than, integration doesn't work that way. When you want to integrate like that, you have to choose a path in $\Bbb{R}^2$ you can't just integrate arbitrarily like you would in $1$D.

Comment: Separate issue... How did you arrive at the implication at the end?  Wouldn't it be $\dots=Ce^{-x}$?

Comment: X is also a function of y which you don't know so you have to find it

Comment: Thanks, i probably should practice more to understand this better.

Answer (score 2):

Divide both sides by $e^x$:

$$ye^{-x}\:dx + \left(y^{-1}-e^{-x}\right)dy = 0$$

which is conservative (or exact) because

$$\partial_y(ye^{-x}) = \partial_x(-e^{-x})$$

which means there exists a function $f(x,y)$ such that

$$f_xdx + f_ydy = 0$$

and that function is

$$f(x,y)=-ye^{-x}+\ln|y| = C$$

Comment: How did you know to do this? Is there a sign in the equation for this?

Comment: @Alon Unfortunately, I can't give you a better answer than this is a known, very common technique to solve these kinds of differential equations.

Comment: Ok that’s not new in math, usually it comes with practice those things as for my experience, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, if you to find an appropriate integrating factor to make a diff eq exact, you need to solve the equation $$\frac{\partial(uy)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{ue^x}{y}-u\Big)$$ for $u$. Note that $u$ may be a function of $x$ and $y$. This yields $$u+yu_{y}=\frac{1}{y}\big[ue^x+e^xu_x\big]-u_x$$
If you assume that $u$ is only a function of $x$, then the above equation reduces to $$u=\frac{1}{y}\big[ue^x+e^xu'\big]-u'$$Simplify to get $u'=-u$. A solution to this is $u=e^{-x}$.  Once you have this integrating factor, you can proceed to finding the potential function that generates your solution curves.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equation in the form $$y\,x' + \frac{e^x}{y}-1 = 0$$ Let $x=\log(t)$ to make
$$y^2 t'-y t+t^2=0\implies t=\frac{y}{c_1+\log (y)}\implies x=\log \left(\frac{y}{c_1+\log (y)}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \int \left( \frac{e^x} y - 1\right) \, dy$ is not $e^x\ln\left| y \right| - y + \text{constant}$ because $x$ is not a constant: $x$ changes as $y$ changes.